# Site to site VPN from Amazon EC2 to Checkpoint device

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, redhat

I have an EC2 with Red Hat 7 in AWS and I need to connect it to a network via VPN.

I followed the instructions here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Securing_Virtual_Private_Networks.html#sec-IPsec_VPN_Using_Libreswan to install and configure Libreswan in Red Hat.

The connetion to the VPN is established but the routing does not work. I can not get a response from the host in the remote network.

The config for ipsec is like this:

```
conn site-to-site
    type=tunnel
    authby=secret
    auto=route
    ike=3des-sha1
    phase2=esp
    phase2alg=3des-sha1
    nat-ikev1-method=rfc
    pfs=no
    forceencaps=yes

    left=%defaultroute
    leftid={elastic_ip}
    leftsourceip=172.31.34.9
    leftsubnet=172.31.34.9/32

    right={remote_ip}
    rightid={remote_ip}
    rightsourceip=192.168.253.155
    rightsubnet=192.168.253.155/32
```

Any help to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

After some help from @bleve and @LetoTo in the IRC #swan I changed the config like this:

```
left={local_ip}
leftid={elastic_ip}
leftsourceip={elastic_ip}
leftsubnet={elastic_ip}/32
```

And now works.
This line was added to the routing table after connecting the VPN:

```
192.168.253.155 dev eth0  scope link  src 52.6.108.86
```

Comment: The only one of these that I suspect may give you difficulty is `leftsubnet`.  If (and it's something of a big if) my understanding is entirely right, this will not allow the other end to access anything else inside AWS.  If that turns out to be true, and is an issue requiring more troubleshooting, I'd leave the other three alone -- they are definitely correct, in my experience.

Comment: In this case all I need is to access the server in the right side, there should be no need to access the left side from the right